# Tikz/pgfplot: draw option to plot a plot file at given position

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to use the draw function of the `tikz` package to plot a 
2D experimental data at a given z altitude.
Since I am using some kind of projection view, I would like to fix the *z* position of the `\draw[option] plot[option] file {Dat.dat}`, in which `Dat.dat` is the file composed of x, y components.

Basically I would like to draw this plot at `*z* = -3`, and then use \draw function to draw rectangle and ball on top on it with a 3D like view.
I am able to draw the different geometries (balls and cubes), but I cannot plot `Dat.dat` at the z altitude I want.

Does someone know the draw option allowing it?

Best

PS: below a light version of my drawing

```
\documentclass[11pt]{Tikzfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[show grid = false,x={(0.866cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1.0,>=stealth, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,axis/.style={thick,->},
wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth},polaroid/.style={fill=black!60!white, opacity=0.3},] 

\draw[color=blue] plot[smooth,mark size=1pt] file {Dat.dat};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could also add -- at least a light version -- of your `Dat.dat` to your code like in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299536/non-uniform-colormap) question/answer. Then we have an idea of how your data look like and then it maybe much simpler to provide an adequate solution.

Comment: Is **Tikzfigure** a documentclass?